# Problem in setting hudson home directory

Tags: hudson

I was trying to install CI tool Hudson on a Solaris SPARC by deploying hudson.war to the jboss AS. I made changes in run.conf to point to the correct jdk ( setting environment variables JAVA_HOME and JAVA), and other required changes like setting JAVA_OPTS etc. I also set an env variable HUDSON_HOME= to point the hudson home directory. When I run the AS by command ' nohup JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -c all & '  everything seems to be OK. I am able to access Hudson dashboard by the URL 'http://:8080/hudson ' .
                         But the hudson home directory remains to be the same:  '.hudson ' directory in my home directory, as it should have been by default. The directory I had pointed by the variable HUDSON_HOME is not taken as the hudson home directory. I don't know why this is happening.
                         Is there any other way to specify home directory for hudson??

Answer (score 2):

Restart Hudsun complete not only sending a signal. Why are you using JBOSS and not Tomcat or the internal Jetty of Hudson itself ?...